# python timestamp to js timestamp

Tags: javascript, python

Now I want to transfer timstamp() in Python into timstamp() in JS. But the problem is Python uses seconds, while JS uses milliseconds. 
How can I transfer Python's version into JS? For example:

1. For Python

   ```
   python_stamp = int(time.mktime(time.gmtime()))
   ```

   then the output is

   ```
   python_stamp=1481269558
   ```
2. But for JS:

   ```
   JS_timestamp = Date().getTime()
   ```

   then the output is

   ```
   JS_timestamp = 1481269558356
   ```

Do you know how to transfer Python's version into JS. By the way, please do not say python_stamp*1000, basically, it is not a solution I want to find.

Comment: JS timestamps are in milliseconds... Python timestamps are in seconds.  What do you mean that multiplying by 1000 isn't a solution that you want to find?  What's wrong with it?

Comment: *`"it is not a solution I want to find."`* That sucks, because that's the best cross-platform way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here are a couple of examples to get milliseconds

```
from datetime import datetime

print(int(datetime.now().strftime("%s%f")) / 1000)
```

example 2

```
from time import time

print(time())  # 1481253947.930211
print(int(time() * 1000))  # 1481253947930
```